# C言語で降順に番号を振りたいが、番号が被る

Tags: c, array

C言語で, datファイルから数値を読み取ってそれを降順に番号を振るプログラムを作っているのですが, 同じ大きさの数値同士ではないにもかかわらず, 番号が重複してしまいます. どなたか教えてくださると幸いです. 以下datとcのソースコードです.

```
コンパイル;gcc test.c -o test
実行;./test test.dat
実行結果;
11は4番
2は4番
842は1番
675は2番
435は3番
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
{
  FILE *fp;                                 /* 変数定義 */
  int a[N];
  int i,data;
  int j;
  int juni;

/*------- ファイルからデータの読み込み ---------*/

  if(argc != 2){                            /* 引数は２つあるか */
    puts("Parameter Error");
    return 0;
  }

  if((fp = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL){    /* ファイルは存在するか */
    puts("File Open Error"); 
    return 0;
  }

  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &data);
    a[i] = data;
    juni = 1;

    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        if(a[i] < a[j]){
            //printf("%d\n",a[j]);
            juni++;
            //printf("%dと%dを比較!\n", a[i],a[j]);
        }
    }
    printf("%dは%d番\n",a[i],juni);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

test.dat

```
11
2
842
675
435
```

Comment: まだファイルからN個のデータを読み取り終わっていないのに、1個のデータを読み取るたびに、N個のデータを比較参照していますね。もう一度プログラムの流れを考え直しましょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一度datファイルから数値を全部読み込んでから、降順にソートした方がいいと思います。
実装例は以下のようになります。

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5

// 降順ソート用の構造体
typedef struct{
    // ファイルから読み取った値を格納
    int score;
    // ソート前のindexを格納
    int index;
} element;

// qsort関数用の降順ソート用の関数
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return  ((element*) b)->score - ((element*) a)->score;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *fp;                                 /* 変数定義 */
  int a[N];
  // 順位格納用
  int juni[N];
  // ソート用の配列
  element elements[N];
  int i,data;

/*------- ファイルからデータの読み込み ---------*/

  if(argc != 2){                            /* 引数は２つあるか */
    puts("Parameter Error");
    return 0;
  }

  if((fp = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL){    /* ファイルは存在するか */
    puts("File Open Error");
    return 0;
  }

  // ファイルから読み込む
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &data);
    a[i] = data;
  }
  
  // ソート用の配列へ値の設定
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
      // ファイルから読み取った値を格納する
      elements[i].score = a[i];
      // ソート前のindexを格納する
      elements[i].index = i;
  }

  // 降順ソートを実施する
  qsort(elements,N,sizeof(element),compare);

  // 降順ソートした結果を順位の配列に格納する
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
      juni[elements[i].index] = i + 1 ;
  }

  // 結果を出力する
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
      printf("%dは%d番\n",a[i],juni[i]);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```